# AVPlayer playback rate for AVComposition

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation, avplayer, avcomposition

I am using an `AVPlayer` to handle playback of multiple assets by putting them all in an `AVMutableComposition`.  Everything works for normal playback, i.e. `[player play]`, but when I try something like `[player setRate:0.5]`, only one of the tracks in the composition slows down to half speed.  So I still have two tracks playing at the same time, but one is half speed and the other is full speed.

Does anyone have any idea how to get them both to slow down to the desired playback speed? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

you should use `AVComposition` instead of `AVMutableComposition` for `AVPlayer` purposes

```
AVComposition *immutableSnapshotOfMyComposition = [myMutableComposition copy];
```